# Can interconnected smoke detectors be wired as spokes from an attic junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, smoke-detectors

Suppose 3 interconnected smoke detectors on first floor.  Standard wiring would run 14/2 to first, then 14/3 (with red wire for interconnecting) to second, then 14/3 to third.  My question is whether this alternative wiring would be acceptable, especially considering all smoke detectors should alarm when any detects smoke.

Alternative wiring: 14/2 runs from breaker to a single junction box in the attic. Then three cables (14/3) run to each smoke detector from the junction box. All white wires would be connected in the junction box; same for black wires; same for red wires.

Comment: This is down to the instructions for that particular product.

Comment: @VtC - Where is the OP asking for a product recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For typical interconnected smoke alarms, this is fine

For the typical hardwired interconnections found on North American smoke alarms, this is alright -- they don't care about the topology of the wiring, only that the interconnect wire connects the smoke detectors together.

Comment: Just curious, which FACPs care about wiring topology?

Comment: @DrSparks -- the OP is likely not aware of the distinction between "smoke detectors" that go with a FACP and "smoke alarms" that stand alone/are interconnected to each other only.  Conventional smoke detectors (2-wire and 4-wire) generally do care about topology to provide supervision (can't T-tap traditional supervised contact-closure circuits), most addressable systems are fairly free-topology with their SLCs tho

Comment: Gotcha. I've encountered those systems. They had a resistor at the end of the chain to complete the loop. Addressable systems are certainly preferred, simply for the ability to more accurately determine the location of a fire.

Answer (score 1):

The hub and spoke topology not only is not prohibited by Code, but may be a more electrically sound design. Fewer points of failure and shorter overall runs of cable. It does, however, introduce a single point of failure and eliminate some redundancy, so it's a give and take situation.

Luckily, all hardwired smoke detectors come with a 9v battery backup and the system will annoy you for the rest of eternity until you replace the battery.